# Scope of state in callback within hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In the `useEffect` hook below, how can I get access to my `done` state? (It looks like a scope problem)

```js
// Done state
const [done, setIsDone] = useState(false);

// At the start
useEffect(() => {

    // Run every second
    const to = setInterval(() => {

        // Abort if neccessary
        if(done) return;

        // Do stuff...

    }, 1000);

    // Specify how to clean up after this effect
    return () => clearInterval(to);
}, []);
```

Comment: The function you pass to `setInterval` only has access to the value that `done` has at the moment `setInterval` was called. You are explicitly telling `useEffect` that it doesn't depend on any state values, which isn't true: You are depending on `done`. So you could add `[done]` as dependency, but that would also cancel and recreate the interval every time `done` changes. A better approach might be use use a ref so that you can always access the "current" value. However, Dan actuall wrote about this a while back: https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using refs

```
const done = useRef(false);
```

Then you can make these helpers

```
const getIsDone = () => done.current;
const setIsDone = () => (done.current = isDone);
```

Then this will work as expected in your `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const to = setInterval(() => {

        // always returns the 'live' value of `done` without closing over the old value
        if (getIsDone()) {problems
...
```